# Terraform wrappers - Does everyone build their own + any good wrappers out there besides gruntworks?

Tags: terraform

I've been using Terraform to provision my infrastructure that has been up to this point immutable but I need to transition to to a use case where my infrastructure needs to change frequently based on user commands.

My question is are most people building their own Terraform wrappers?  Are there any good wrappers out there that people are using besides gruntworks?  I work in python and have found [Claranet Terraform Wrapper](https://github.com/claranet/terraform-wrapper) but it isn't quite what I am looking for.  Open to looking at other languages.

Comment: I thought most of the functionality in terragrunt ended up being implemented in core Terraform.

Comment: That was what initially turned me away from them (ie remote state and locking) which was incorporated in core but then taking a fresh look recently it seems like they have done a lot more than that.  I'm probably just going to adopt their tool set because of the "before and after hooks" feature and just wrap it all in python.

Comment: I always use my own wrapper. For the most part it is a small script.

Comment: A Makefile can be a good wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Use your own bash wrapper, it will be small, flexible and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

##### Node.js/Yarn Terraform CLI wrapper (example)

```
import spawn from "cross-spawn";

const args = process.argv.slice(2);

// TODO: Manipulate args, etc.

spawn("terraform", args, {
  // Customize working directory
  cwd: process.cwd(),
  env: {
    ...process.env,
    // Customize environment variables
    // https://www.terraform.io/cli/config/environment-variables
    // TF_DATA_DIR: ...,
    // TF_CLI_CONFIG_FILE: ...,
    // TF_WORKSPACE: ...

  },
  studio: "inherit"
}).on("exit", code => {
  if (code) process.exitCode = code;
});
```

Usage example:

```
$ yarn tf plan
$ yarn tf apply -auto-approve
```

See [Terraform Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/terraform-starter-kit#readme) repository on GitHub (`scripts/tf.js`).